# Overflow error in vba code in addition

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA, please help me to resolve below.

While running below facing `OVERFLOW` error:

```
total = 0
employee = InputBox("Enter the employee Name")

For Each sheet In Worksheets
  For i = 2 To 13

    If sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = employee Then
       total = sheet.Cells(i, 3).Value + total
    End If
   Next i
Next sheet
```

Comment: What data type is total? What values are there to total? Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are potentially overflowing the `total` variable as it's probably defaulting to an INTEGER for storage which can only hold up to two bytes (-32768 to 32767).

Instead declare your variable with a type that can hold more data:

```
Dim total as Long
total = 0
employee = InputBox("ENter the employee Name")

For Each sheet In Worksheets
        For i = 2 To 13

        If sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = employee Then

               total = sheet.Cells(i, 3).Value + total

        End If

   Next i
Next sheet
```

Comment: ... or `Long` if appropriate.

Comment: @AndyG Thought the same and changed it :)

Comment: It's probably declared as an Integer as Variant is the default.

Comment: thank you @Jnevill i declared int as total.